# Initializing static member function pointer to function of same name

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I got segfaults and could boild down the code to this; I initialize a static function pointer that is a member with a global function of the same name:

```
#include <iostream>

class def{
        public:
static void (*pt)();
};

void pt()
{
        std::cout << "works" << std::endl;
}

void (*def::pt)()=pt;
main(int argc,char* args[])
{
  std::cout << "pointer is " << def::pt << std::endl;
  def::pt();
}
```

This gives

```
pointer is 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So the initalization seems to fail. If I now change the name of the function in the initialization to something else, say:

```
[...]        
void pt2()
{
        std::cout << "works" << std::endl;
}

void (*def::pt)()=pt2;
[...]
```

This resolves the problem. I am wondering what is going wrong there. Is that a scoping issue?

Comment: `void (*def::pt)() = ::pt;` should work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void (*def::pt)()=pt;
```

Because you are defining a static member of `def`, names declared in `def` shadow names declared without.

You can select the correct version of `pt` by explicitly specifying `pt` in the global namespace:

```
void (*def::pt)() = ::pt;
//                  ^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Do you mean the global function is shadowed _in that line_ or in the whole file? edit; I see, it is only that line. Okay, thank you again!